# VScode JS syntax color for Object Key

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to set color for object key: `{key:'string'}`

Closer I got is adding in `settings.json` this:
`"workbench.colorCustomizations": {}`,

But what settings should I add further?

Comment: similar and possibly same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65223636/11107541

Answer (score 2):

If the OP or anyone is still looking for an answer to this question.

In your `settings.json` file

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
    {
                "scope": "meta.object-literal.key",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000", // any color you like
                    // any other styling you want to apply
                }
            }
      ]
}
```

to get the correct scope you can open up the command panel on your javascript/typescript/any file in vscode with
`cmd`+`shift`+`p` or
`ctrl`+`shift`+`p` on a PC.

Search: `>Developer: inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`
Then you can click on specific syntax to get the correct scope.
You'll get something looking like this:
[image]

If you want the styling to only apply to a specific theme
the following will help you
https://egghead.io/lessons/vs-code-adding-custom-syntax-highlighting-to-a-theme-in-vscode