# VS Code Set JavaScript Property color

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out how to change object property colors in JS files in VS Code.  For example:

```
var vehicle = {
    type: "Fiat",
    model: "500",
    color: "white"
};
```

How would I set the color for "type, model and color" properties?

I was thinking this would work in settings.json, but it does not:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "functions": {
        "fontStyle": ""
    },
    "[TommyTachas]": {
        "comments": "#db33a3",
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "support.type.property-name.js",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff0000"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The scope to use is `variable.other.property.js`

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      { "scope":"variable.other.property.js",
        "settings": {"foreground": "#00ff00"}
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
     "[your current theme]": {
        "rules": {
        "property": "#AE81FF"
     }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case if you want to change the var color it'll be "storage.type.js"

The following link has the information you are look for.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76308?msclkid=bfff79bec58d11eca167869d42275429