# VsCode, how to change Javascript Object key colours

Tags: javascript, themes, visual-studio-code

I am currently struggling a little to change the colour of keys inside javascript objects in my vscode theme. Hoping someone could help me out.

[image: Vscode theme demonstration]

As you can see, the keys end up being the same colour as strings, which is a little annoying to me. Looking to change it to something else. Anyone know what to do? I probably need to change some css settings but can't find the right one.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: what colour theme are you using?

Comment: With default (I think) settings on W10 I see dark blue `let`, and ligher blue `obj`, `hello`, `variable`, `value`, and orangeish string literal.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - yes, I think that's called `Dark+ (default)`

Comment: @Bravo I am using the theme Andromeda from the extensions page. Within the package I am using Andromeda Italic.

Comment: @Julian-Life - How to customise colours in a theme is [documented here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VScode JS syntax color for Object Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746482/vscode-js-syntax-color-for-object-key)

Answer (score -3):

Hi maybe the easiest way is to change your vscode theme :

Here Material theme :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme